# Ansible > alias to host in inventory

Tags: ansible, inventory

I have an inventory which, for the purposes of testing, uses the same host for all groups:

```
[webserver]
127.0.0.1 ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=somepassword

[dbserver]
127.0.0.1 ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=somepassword

[storageserver]
127.0.0.1 ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=somepassword
```

Is it possible to alias this host?

If I use this:

```
[localvm]
127.0.0.1 ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=somepassword

[webserver]
localvm   

[dbserver]
localvm   

[storageserver]
localvm
```

I get `fatal: [localvm]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname localvm: Name or service not known\r\n", "unreachable": true}`.

This works:

```
[localvm]
127.0.0.1 ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=somepassword

[webserver:children]
localvm   

[dbserver:children]
localvm   

[storageserver:children]
localvm
```

i.e. I'm specifying `localvm` as a group (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html ) however it's not what I'm wanting to do. I want to create an alias for `127.0.0.1` called `localvm`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why is it you don't want to use `:children` ? Is there any issue with it ?

Comment: Because the docs say this is for creating groups of groups (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html) whereas I'm wanting to create a host alias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want inventory name for the host to be different to actual host name, you can use `ansible_host` variable. See [List of Behavioral Inventory Parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

Like this:

```
[webserver]
localvm ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=somepassword

[dbserver]
localvm

[storageserver]
localvm
```

I often define hosts as ungrouped entries and then add them to required groups, like this:

```
www1 ansible_host=10.10.10.10
db1 ansible_host=10.10.10.20

[web]
www1

[database]
db1
```

Comment: Does that mean that each of the other localvm's listed then automatically pick up the variables you've set under webserver?